# how do i disappear food from inside snake with python?

Tags: python, function, if-statement, while-loop

I want to make the food disappear from the snake when it eats the food but the string stays visible inside snake making the snake look weird with the food in the snake... now what I been trying is this line of code:

Error ( 'tuple' object has no attribute 'replace' )

```
  for food in snake: 

      food = food.replace(food, ' ')
```

I just started writting code not too long ago... i only know the basics of python but still confusing and I'm trying to learn as i work in this project to make the game better...

This is the python Script:

```
import curses
from mimetypes import init 
from random import randint


WINDOW_WIDTH = 60
WINDOW_HEIGHT = 20

# Set Up 

curses.initscr()
win = curses.newwin(WINDOW_HEIGHT, WINDOW_WIDTH, 0, 0) # y, x
win.keypad(1)
curses.noecho()
curses.curs_set(0)
win.border(0)
win.nodelay(1)

# Snake And Food

snake = [(4, 10), (4, 9), (4, 8)]
food = (10, 10)

win.addch(food[0], food[1], '⊠')

# Game Logic 

score = 0

ESC = 27
key = curses.KEY_RIGHT 

while key != ESC:
   win.addstr(0, 2, 'score ' + str(score) + ' ')
   win.timeout(150 - (len(snake)) // 5 + len(snake)//10 % 120)

   prev_key = key
   event = win.getch()
   key = event if event != -1 else prev_key

   if key not in [curses.KEY_LEFT, curses.KEY_RIGHT, curses.KEY_UP, curses.KEY_DOWN, ESC]:
    prev_key

   # Calculating Coordinates 

   y = snake[0][0]
   x = snake[0][1]
   if key == curses.KEY_DOWN:
        y += 1 
   if key == curses.KEY_UP:
        y -= 1 
   if key == curses.KEY_LEFT:
        x -= 1         
   if key == curses.KEY_RIGHT:
        x += 1 

   snake.insert(0, (y, x))

   # Hit Border Reboot

   if y == 0: break
   if y == WINDOW_HEIGHT-1: break
   if x == 0: break
   if x == WINDOW_WIDTH-1: break

   # dead.Self Snake 

   if snake[0] in snake[1:]: break

   if snake[0] == food:
    
    # Eat The Food
    
    score += 1 
    food = ()
    while food == ():
        food = (randint(1,WINDOW_HEIGHT-2), randint(1,WINDOW_WIDTH-2))
        if food in snake:
            food = ()            

    win.addch(food[0], food[1], '⊠')
else:
    
    # Move Snake
    
    last = snake.pop()
    win.addch(last[0], last[1], ' ')

    win.addch(snake[0][0], snake[0][1], '▇')

    # Working in Making the food Disappear inside snake
    
    curses.endwin()
    print(f"Final score = {score}")
```

I'm trying to figure out if it goes at the bottom of the code or somewhere else... I try a few things ex: While, If, and different variables...

P.s. ((I just wrote the code but is not mines I did'nt copy & paste neither...))

Please Help!!....